# Play 2.2.1: intellijCommandSettings("JAVA") not working

Tags: java, playframework

In Play 2.1.1, I used in Build.scala :

```
override def settings = super.settings ++ play.Project.intellijCommandSettings("JAVA")
```

Now, I use Play 2.2.1. But intellijCommandSettings("JAVA") is not working anymore:

```
found   : String("JAVA")
required: Int
override def settings = super.settings ++ play.Project.intellijCommandSettings("JAVA")
                                                                               ^ 
one error found
(compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

What should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure but change `play.Project.intellijCommandSettings("JAVA")` to `play.PlayProject.intellijCommandSettings("JAVA")`...

Comment: also see this https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1665#issuecomment-24467734

Comment: Yes. I say that post. But "JAVA" is not present anymore (only intellijCommandSettings). When I do "play idea with-suorces=yes", will he still do a java project or a scala project?